# How to yield from an async for loop using asyncio?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm trying to write a simple asynchronous data batch generator, but having troubles with understanding how to yield from an async for loop. Here I've written a simple class illustrating my idea:

```
import asyncio
from typing import List

class AsyncSimpleIterator:
    def __init__(self, data: List[str], batch_size=None):
        self.data = data
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.doc2index = self.get_doc_ids()

    def get_doc_ids(self):
        return list(range(len(self.data)))

    async def get_batch_data(self, doc_ids):
        print("get_batch_data() running")
        page = [self.data[j] for j in doc_ids]
        return page

    async def get_docs(self, batch_size):
        print("get_docs() running")

        _batch_size = self.batch_size or batch_size
        batches = [self.doc2index[i:i + _batch_size] for i in
                   range(0, len(self.doc2index), _batch_size)]

        for _, doc_ids in enumerate(batches):
            docs = await self.get_batch_data(doc_ids)
            yield docs, doc_ids

    async def main(self):
        print("main() running")
        async for res in self.get_docs(batch_size=2):
            print(res)  # how to yield instead of print?

    def gen_batches(self):
        # how to get results of self.main() here?
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        loop.run_until_complete(self.main())
        loop.close()


 DATA = ["Hello, world!"] * 4
 iterator = AsyncSimpleIterator(DATA)
 iterator.gen_batches()
```

So, my question is, **how to yield a result from `main()` to gather it inside `gen_batches()`**?

When I print the result inside `main()`, I get the following output:

```
main() running
get_docs() running
get_batch_data() running
(['Hello, world!', 'Hello, world!'], [0, 1])
get_batch_data() running
(['Hello, world!', 'Hello, world!'], [2, 3])
```

Comment: Is `gen_batches()` uspposed to exhaust all of `main()`, or only one iteration? Why do you want to `yield` from `main()`?

Comment: @user4815162342 Yes, the generator in `main()` should exhaust in gen_batches(), so I can gather _all_ results in gen_batches(). In a real world gen_batches() functionality would be a part of some other class and it should asynchronously get results from `main()`.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to write a simple asynchronous data batch generator, but having troubles with understanding how to yield from an async for loop

Yielding from an `async for` works like a regular yield, except that it also has to be collected by an `async for` or equivalent. For example, the `yield` in `get_docs` makes it an async generator. If you replace `print(res)` with `yield res` in `main()`, it will make `main()` an async generator as well.

> the generator in `main()` should exhaust in `gen_batches()`, so I can gather *all* results in `gen_batches()`

To collect the values produced by an async generator (such as `main()` with `print(res)` replaced with `yield res`), you can use a helper coroutine:

```
def gen_batches(self):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    async def collect():
        return [item async for item in self.main()]
    items = loop.run_until_complete(collect())
    loop.close()
    return items
```

The `collect()` helper makes use of a [PEP 530](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0530/) asynchronous comprehension, which can be thought of as syntactic sugar for the more explicit:

```
    async def collect():
        l = []
        async for item in self.main():
            l.append(item)
        return l
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize that I can yield from an async for loop only inside another async for loop. I've rewritten the code with your hints and will post it below.

Answer (score 0):

A working solution based on @user4815162342 answer to the original question:

```
import asyncio
from typing import List


class AsyncSimpleIterator:

def __init__(self, data: List[str], batch_size=None):
    self.data = data
    self.batch_size = batch_size
    self.doc2index = self.get_doc_ids()

def get_doc_ids(self):
    return list(range(len(self.data)))

async def get_batch_data(self, doc_ids):
    print("get_batch_data() running")
    page = [self.data[j] for j in doc_ids]
    return page

async def get_docs(self, batch_size):
    print("get_docs() running")

    _batch_size = self.batch_size or batch_size
    batches = [self.doc2index[i:i + _batch_size] for i in
               range(0, len(self.doc2index), _batch_size)]

    for _, doc_ids in enumerate(batches):
        docs = await self.get_batch_data(doc_ids)
        yield docs, doc_ids

def gen_batches(self):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    async def collect():
        return [j async for j in self.get_docs(batch_size=2)]

    items = loop.run_until_complete(collect())
    loop.close()
    return items


DATA = ["Hello, world!"] * 4
iterator = AsyncSimpleIterator(DATA)
result = iterator.gen_batches()
print(result)
```